# pyqt4 py2exe add icon

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4, py2exe

I am using pyqt4, icon is added.

```
basis = sys.argv[0]
required_folder = os.path.split(basis)[0]
# print required_folder
imagepath = required_folder + '\mark.JPG' 
icon = QtGui.QIcon()

icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8(imagepath)), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
MainWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
```

In setup.py for py2exe, I am trying to add my icon to resources.

```
#setup.py

from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(
    windows=[{"script": "MainFile.py"}],
    options={
        "py2exe":
        {
            "dll_excludes" : ["MSVCP90.dll"],
            "includes": ['encodings', 'encodings.*']
        }
    }
)
```

When I start my program from IDE as python script, I see my icon. When I create exe program with py2exe, my program works well, but icon dissappears.
[image]

=======================================================================

I already fixed it. So, Here is my code.
[image]

py2exe is not imported. Why cannot imported?

===========================================================================
I changed the code. When I run py2exe on cmd. "Unexpected shutdown error"
*** copy data files *** <- Stop running.

```
setup(
windows=[{"script": "2017_12_01.py", "icon_resources": [(1, "mark.jpg")]}],
data_files = [('imageformats', [r'C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\plugins\imageformats\qjpeg4.dll'])],
options={
    "py2exe":
    {
        "dll_excludes" : ["MSVCP90.dll"],
        "includes": ['encodings', 'encodings.*', "sip"]

    }
},
```

)

I executed this code.
[image]

Comment: Okay, i really tried. Py2exe is not the easiest for beginners and you have problem after problem. Please try: PyInstaller. Just open the shell (cmd for windows) `pip install pyinstaller` and then `pyinstaller path/to/your/file.py -i path/to/your/icon.ico` and done :)

Comment: Or, if you wanna stick with it: http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial#Step52

Comment: Sadly, pyinstaller is not working. Please one more check about py2exe. I changed my code.

Answer (score 0):

This should add your icon as resource. Just make sure its a ".ico":

```
"icon_resources": [(1, "myicon.ico")]
```

In your code, it should be implemented like the following:

```
#setup.py

from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(
    windows = [
        {
            "script": "MainFile.py",
            "icon_resources": [(1, "myicon.ico")]
        }
    ],
options={
        "py2exe":
        {
            "dll_excludes" : ["MSVCP90.dll"],
            "includes": ['encodings', 'encodings.*']
        }
        }
)
```

Source:
http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/CustomIcons

Comment: Do I have to change the image file format .jpg to .ico ?

Comment: I made both mark.ico and mark.jpg. And then I implemented.  But when I double clicked exe file. It shows "Runtime Error! R6034 An application has made an attempt to load the C runtime library incorrectly. Please contact the application's support team for more information."

Comment: Also, i recommend PyInstaller. Never made a problem with whatever i threw at it. Just open the shell (cmd for windows) `pip install pyinstaller` and then `pyinstaller path/to/your/file.py -i path/to/your/icon.ico` and done.

Comment: Hmm, that must be a problem with the MSVCP90.dll. Did you change "with_gui.py" to your script? Did you import the libraries? And are using a supported Python Version? Changed the code to support copy+paste now

Comment: What is that mean? What's the "with_gui.py"? How can I import the libraries? what libraries?

Comment: I didn't set the `"script": "MainFile.py"` to your script, when i made the example code for you. If you just copy/pasted what i gave you, you get an error. Also you need to import `from distutils.core import setup` and `import py2exe`. But you should be able to copy my code now, as i changed these things now

Comment: I changed my code already. So, I uploaded please one more check.